# \NewDocumentCommand: Mandatory types r / R and their “default values”

Tags: xparse, arguments

The [documentation of `xparse`](//texdoc.net/pkg/xparse) states (emphasis mine):

> *`r`* Given as `r⟨token1⟩⟨token2⟩`, this denotes a “required” delimited argument, where the delimiters are `⟨token1⟩` and `⟨token2⟩`. **If the opening delimiter `⟨token1⟩` is
> missing, the default marker `-NoValue-` will be inserted after a suitable error.**
> *`R`* Given as `R⟨token1⟩⟨token2⟩{⟨default⟩}`, this is a “required” delimited argument as for `r`, **but it has a user-definable recovery `⟨default⟩` instead of `-NoValue-`**.

However in both cases, an error is produced if the parameter is not specified. And I can't see any difference in the error message between `r` and `R`.

- How exactly does this *default marker *`-NoValue-`** intervene?
- And what is the purpose of this additional `{⟨default⟩}`? Any use case?

Is it to avoid additional errors where the corresponding parameter `#N` is used? Or (for `R`) somehow document the parameter with that default value? Any notable difference between `r` and `R` in the end?

Note: I already know about the related optional types `d`/`D`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do a test:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{r<>}{?#1?}

\begin{document}

\test<X>

\test X

\end{document}
```

Upon running LaTeX on it we get

```
! LaTeX cmd Error: Required argument missing for command '\test'.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.9 \test X
```

and the output is

[image]

You see that, in order to recover from the error, LaTeX inserts `<-NoValue>` after `\test`, so processing can continue without a possible further error from a missing `>`. The output would be invalid anyway.

Second test.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{R<>{what}}{?#1?}

\begin{document}

\test<X>

\test X

\end{document}
```

The error message is the same, but now the output is

[image]

Instead of “what” you can use something different that will catch your attention in the PDF file. Better than `-NoValue-`. This might also be useful if you do something more complicated with the argument, so you can perhaps avoid further error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **egreg** for the very detailed answer!
I'd like to add another interesting usecase I just found for a required argument default marker/value.

Let's assume I want to split one argument and be able to pass 1, 2 or 3 values :

```
\test{1, 2, 3}
\test{1, 2}
\test{1}
```

Using:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ >{ \SplitArgument{2}{,} } m }{\impl #1}
```

`\impl` will respectivelly receive

```
\impl{1}{2}{3}
\impl{1}{2}{-NoValue-}
\impl{1}{-NoValue-}{-NoValue-}
```

optional arguments will fail here as the arguments are passed no matter what, with `{}`.

```
\NewDocumentCommand\impl{m m m}{%
    \#1 = #1,
    \#2 = \IfValueTF{#2}{#2}{default},
    \#3 = \IfValueTF{#3}{#3}{default}
}
```

outputs:

```
#1 = 1, #2 = 2, #3 = 3
#1 = 1, #2 = 2, #3 = default
#1 = 1, #2 = default, #3 = default
```